# How to get the proper Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server

Table1

```
ID Actual_Intime Actual_Outtime

001 08:00:00 18:00:00 (HHMMSS)
002 20:00:00 06:00:00
003 05:00:00 14:00:00
004 19:30:00 03:30:00
...
```

...

```
Actual_Intime Datatype is nvarchar
Actual_Outtime Datatype is nvarchar
```

I need to validate the employee time like

"If outtime is less than Intime, then it should take the intime and outtime on the same day"

"if outtime is greater than intime, then it should take the intime on the same day and outtime should be the next day.

Table2

```
ID Date Time

001 20100102 06:00:00
001 20100102 08:00:00
001 20100102 14:00:00
001 20100102 19:00:00
002 20100102 19:00:00
002 20100102 21:00:00
002 20100103 03:00:00
002 20100103 07:00:00
...,
```

...

```
Date Datatype is nvarchar
Time Datetype is nvarchar

Date Format: yyyymmdd
Time Format: HHMMSS
```

I need to take the Min(time) and Max(time) from the table2 but table2 compare the actual intime and actual outtime from table1

Expected Output

```
ID Date Intime Outtime

001 20100102 06:00:00 19:00:00
```

(Here Actual_Outtime is less than Actual_Intime from table1, so In table2 it should take the intime and outtime on the same day)

```
002 20100102 19:00:00 07:00:00
```

(Here Actual_Outtime  is greater than Actual_Intime from table1, so In table2 it should take the next day time as outtime)

How to get the Intime and Outtime compare with actual Intime and actual Outtime from Table1.

Need Query Help

Comment: shouldn't the 2nd one be 19 - 7 instead of 21 - 7?

Comment: Why are you using `nvarchar` for this? You won't be storing Unicode characters so are just waiting space. Additionally the length is not variable so you are wasting another couple of bytes per row there. If you must store it as a string at all use `char(8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether `Table1` is actually needed here. I understand, `Table2` contains all the necessary information to generate the result table.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  date =    CONVERT(char(8), intime,  112),
  intime =  CONVERT(char(8), intime,  108),
  outtime = CONVERT(char(8), outtime, 108)
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    intime =  MIN(dt),
    outtime = MAX(dt)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      ID,
      dt = CAST(Actual_Intime + ' ' + Actual_Outtime AS datetime)
    FROM Table2
  ) s
) m
```

I assume here that `Table1.Actual_Intime` corresponds to `MIN(CAST(Table2.Date + ' ' + Table2.Time AS datetime))`, and `Table1.Actual_Outtime` to `MAX(...)`, which seems to agree with the description given.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I need to take the min(time) and max(time) from table 2, but your query is confused me.

Comment: @Gopal: Why, I used `Table1` instead of `Table2`, silly me! Of course it was confusing. Sorry, I've fixed it now.